Converting circular structure to JSON error help pls
I'm trying to send a post request to my local c# backend but also getting this error. Is there anyone know why?
I took a look to "Circular Reference" topic but cant find anything usefull
I check my itemAddForm variable several times and it should be the problem. But i cant see what is it as junior
export class ItemaddComponent implements OnInit {
  itemaddForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFormGroup();
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    this.itemaddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,]),
      itemType: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
      ]),
      category: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
      ]),
      genre: new FormControl(),
      publicationDate: new FormControl(),
      totalPages: new FormControl(),
      language: new FormControl(),
      isAvailable:  new FormControl(),
      publisherId:  new FormControl(),
      locationId:  new FormControl(), 
      byPassCache: true,
    });
  }
  submit() {
    this.itemaddForm.markAsDirty();
    if (this.itemaddForm.valid) {
      console.log('tıklandı')
      this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:60805/api/items',this.itemaddForm).subscribe({
        next: (next) => {
          console.log('Backendden cevap geldi:', next);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log('Backendden hatalı cevap geldi:', error);
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.log('Backend isteği sonlandı.');
        },
      });
      console.log(this.itemaddForm.value);
      console.log('tıklandı')
    }
  }
}


The error means that the object you're trying to send has a structure that prevents it from being serialized as JSON. Generally, an object like yours, with all those nested objects like the FormControl values, is unlikely to work as a parameter directly to an API. You have to write code to extract the form parameters in a simpler object in order to send the form content to your API.

Can you explain more?

I am not familiar in detail with the Form tools you are using. It is clear however that you cannot use a "group" as you are trying to do. I suspect that your tools provide an API to extract the form values in some kind of structure that can be used for posting via HTTP.

My teacher told me this structure. He wrote like that and i just switch the variable names.

Did your teacher actually try it?

Yes he tried on fake api but im not getting sure when you say like that

OK, let me repeat: that error means that the value you are passing to .post() cannot be serialized as JSON. I do not know anything about those Form tools, so I do not know exactly why, but if you're getting that error then it's not going to work. Perhaps there is documentation you can read, I don't know.
